# Assigning Variables to Custom Atributes in ASP.net Dynamic Data

Tags: c#

can we assign a value of variable to attribute property. Something like below

i have a variable like

```
string userRole="Admin"
```

and now i want to assign it to role property of security attribute.

```
[Security(role=userRole)]
public partial class Product
{


}
```

If not what is an alternative to this

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: That's not a variable, that's a field and no, you can only assign compile-time constants to an attribute. Are you asking how to change the authorized roles at runtime? Why?

Comment: Is `SecurityAttribute` a real attribute or the syntax you expect to use?

Comment: It's a custom attribute. I have stored list of roles in database & I want to applied it  to Security attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute values must be known at compile time. Otherwise, you can't assign them.

Comment: is there any alternative

Comment: @Mangesh i am afraid not.

Comment: @Mangesh alternative to what? What are you trying to do?